# Understanding Derivation of Euler-Lagrange

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I am trying to understand the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation. I drew a graph below.

[image: graph]

So, according to the graph,

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(x+\delta{x},\dot{x}+\delta\dot{x}\,t)  dt - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(x,\dot{x},t) dt = \delta{S}$$

That is, we take the difference between the integral of the true path and the integral of the variated path, where S is the action defined by $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(x,\dot{x},t) dt$ and $\delta{S}$ is the variation in action (in the graph it is the distance between the blue line and the red line at any t value). Where do I proceed from there? I don't understand this line in the derivation:

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(x,\dot{x},t) dt + \frac{d{L}}{d{x}}\delta{x} + \frac{d{L}}{d{\dot{x}}}\delta{\dot{x}}+O((\delta{x})^2)- L(x,\dot{x},t) dt = \delta{S}$$

(Source: http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/TorontoMathWiki/index.php/Euler-Lagrange_Equation)

Namely, what is the function O? Where are the partial derivatives coming from? The only thing I know to do is to combine the two integrals because the times and the integration variables are the same. How do I get all the mess to the left of $L(x,\dot{x},t)$ in the equation above?

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivatives appear as a result of the chain rule for partial derivatives; this takes place implicitly when the variation is applied to the Lagrangian functional. The big O notation says that there are higher order terms which can be ignored in the variational limit.

The web page shows a couple of ways to obtain the result. Euler used purely geometric methods, and Lagrange invented the variational technique with the delta process.

Comment: The partial derivatives come from the Taylor series

Comment: Although $x, \dot x  $ are dependent, they *can be treated as independent variables *to find $ \delta S $

Comment: @Narasimham: x,x˙ are linearly independent.

Comment: I meant to say that though they are differentially related, they are linearly independent and on that base  calculus of variation is built. Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think about the definition of a derivative,

$$
\frac{df}{dx} = \lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}.
$$

If you rearrange this equation you'll see that

$$
f(x+\delta x) \approx f(x) + \frac{df}{dx} \delta x,
$$
when $\delta x$ is small. As $\delta x$ gets smaller the approximation becomes more exact. The term $\mathcal{O}((\delta x)^2)$ represents some quantity that scales like $(\delta x)^2$ as $\delta x$ goes towards 0. So another way to write the above the equation might be
$$
f(x+\delta x) =f(x) + \frac{df}{dx} \delta x + \mathcal{O}((\delta x)^2).
$$

Comment: This is good for intuition, but the EL equations uses functional derivatives.

Comment: The way I've always seen it, the way to rigorously define these functional derivatives is in terms of ordinary derivatives. I.e. you define a new path as $x(t)$ by $x(t) = x_0(t) + \epsilon \delta x(t)$, where $x_0(t)$ is the path that minimizes the action and $\delta x(t)$ is an arbitrary _but fixed_ function (that vanishes at the end points) and $\epsilon$ is a number. Then you plug in $x(t)$ into Lagrangian, consider the action as a function of $\epsilon$, and take an ordinary derivative with respect to $\epsilon$.

Comment: No, you're right, but you might want to mention that in your answer.

Comment: ... or equivalently to doing the derivative wrt $\epsilon$: at each value of $t$ in the integrand you expand the integrand to first order in $\epsilon$ and demand that the variation in the action is 0 (at first order in $epsilon$) for _every_ possible perturbation $\delta x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

> Namely, what is the function O? Where are the partial derivatives coming from? The only thing I know to do is to combine the two integrals because the times and the integration variables are the same. How do I get all the mess to the left of L(x,x˙,t) in the equation above?

These are good questions. The usual derivation is a heuristic derivation and typically a rigorous derivation of the EL equations in the calculus of variations, at the level of rigour, that a first year undergraduate mathematics degree will approach the calculus of one real variable appears to be fairly rare in the literature.

Abraham & Marsden, in their book, *Foundations of mechanics*, take a geometric approach, which allows them to deduce the EL equations in a rigorous manner, admitting that an analytic derivation is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you've gotten answers to your questions already, but if you haven't, the following may help.

Firstly with regard to your question about the partial derivatives and 'all the stuff to the left of ...':

1. Forget about the 'O((x)) squared. Since x will be going to 0, all this says is that you don't have to worry about terms going to 0 faster even faster. Some smarty pants just put it in to be a mathematician.
2. After you get rid of it, notice that two of the terms cancel out and what you're left with is S = ∫(L/x)x + (L/x')x'. To understand this, think of x and x' not as derivatives of 't' but simply as two variables of the function L. As L rises to L+L, one way to approximate that is to think of the x variable rises from x to (L/x)x in the x direction, and the x' variable rises from (L/x')x' in the x' direction. Each of these is just  the rise in the directions of the underlying variables, and their sum as a measure of the change in L. Is it the actual change in L? No. The actual change would be the square root of some Pythagorean sum of squares. But that doesn't matter. What matters is that this expression will go to 0 at the same rate as that square root, and that's all we're interested in. But in fact, that partial derivative sum is the way you calculate a change in a function in terms of its component changes, and it is what is used in the calculus of variations.
3. Now you simply have to follow the proof by using the chain rule to eliminate the x', factor out the x and get the Euler-Lagrange equation. I'm assuming you know how to do that.

Hope this helps.